# python matplotlib MKL fatal error on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04, intel-mkl

Here's my python code

```
1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                 
2 plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])                                                          
3 plt.ylabel('some numbers')                                                      
4 plt.show()
```

When I run it, I got the following error message

```
$ python test.py 

*** libmkl_avx.so *** failed with error : /usr/local/enthought/lib/libmkl_avx.so: undefined symbol: i_free
*** libmkl_def.so *** failed with error : /usr/local/enthought/lib/libmkl_def.so: undefined symbol: i_free
MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load neither libmkl_avx.so nor libmkl_def.so
```

Here's my python version.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.2 -- EPD 7.2-2 (64-bit)
```

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/300857

Comment: how did you install matplotilb/numpy/scipy?

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with my enthought python installation. When I use standard python2.7, everything is fine.

Comment: I use sudo apt-get to install matplotlib

Comment: The `EPD` in your version indicates this is the Enthought Python Distributation.  That should come with matplotlib already.  It's *possible* that running `sudo apt-get install matplotlib` on top of that created some problems.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a pretty old question, but I was having the same issue and found a solution without needing to reinstall, so for any future readers here is what I did:

@root commented above with a link to the [intel forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/300857).  One of the answers there suggested preloading some of the MKL libraries. (dated Tue, 10/20/2009 - 10:32, I can't figure out how to link to specific comment on there).

This solved the issue for me.  Though, you'll need to find where tthe libmkl_core.so and libmkl_sequential.so libraries are stored for you. For me, it was:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/Canopy/v152/CanopyCore/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.rh5-x86_64/lib/libmkl_sequential.so:/usr/local/Canopy/v152/CanopyCore/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.rh5-x86_64/lib/libmkl_core.so
```

There were also copies in `/usr/local/Canopy/v152/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/`, but these versions did *NOT* work.  Only the one above.

Hope this helps someone out in the future!

Comment: for anaconda the libraries are found in anaconda2/lib/